# Why is this error occurring in AngularJS all of a sudden?

Tags: angularjs

I've been working on a project for quite some time and recently came across this error, which has not occurred before. It happens when using ng-repeat and is stopping from the creation of necessary objects for the system.

Below is a table that display a query of events:

```
  <table class="table custom-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>
                            <!--<th scope="col">Category</th>-->
                            <th scope="col">Organization</th>
                            <th scope="col">Hosted by</th>
                            <th scope="col">Description</th>
                            <th scope="col">Date</th>
                            <th scope="col">Time</th>
                            <th scope="col">Hours</th>
                            <th scope="col"></th>
                            <th scope="col"></th>
<!--                            <th scope="col">
                                <label class="control control--checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-check-all">
                                        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                                </label>
                            </th>-->
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                      <tbody ng-controller="EventRollController as eventRollCtrl">
                        <tr scope="row" data-ng-repeat="event in eventCtrl.events">
                            
                     
                            <td>{{event.eventName}}</td>
                            <!--<td>{{event.category}}</td>-->
                            <td>{{event.organisationName}}</td>
                            <td>{{event.createdBy}}</td>
                            <td>{{event.description}}</td>
                            <td>{{event.date}}</td>
                            <td>{{event.time}}</td>
                            <td>{{event.hoursAvailable}}</td>
                            <td>
                            <button ng-click="eventRollCtrl.selectEvent(event)">Click to sign up to event</button>
                                    
                            </td>
                      
                        
 
                        </tr>
                        
                        
      
        
                    </tbody>
                    
                </table>
```

Error Message: Error: [ngRepeat:iexp] Expected expression in form of '*item* in *collection*[ track by *id*]' but got ''.

Answer (score 0):

Please check it is {{event.organisationName}} or {{event.organizationName}}. There might be a spelling mistake with the data since the code looks good.